# Why am I getting "unable to open database file" on my SQLite table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2019

I added a SQLite database to the root of my project and set its "Build Action" property to "Content":

[image]

I'm trying to open the database this way:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
. . .
string cs = "Data Source=\\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db;";
using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
con.Open();
```

...but the exception "*unable to open database file*" is thrown on the `con.Open()` line above.

I don't want to use the full file path (C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db) to the database, because that's not going to be a valid path for anybody but myself.

Is there something wrong with my connection string that is causing this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, check the `debug` folder on your project that there it is

Next:

```
    var connectoinString=Path.Combine("Data source=", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db")    
  //  or    
    var connectoinString=Path.Combine("Data source=", Application.StartupPath, "F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db")

using var con = new SQLiteConnection(connectoinString);
con.Open();
```

Comment: Which is preferable, to use "Application.StartupPath" or "Environment.CurrentDirectory"? IOW, which one will most likely never cause a problem when the app is running on a user's machine?

Comment: By default, The result is the same for both.
But one of the differences is that you can't set a value for `Application.StartupPath`, But you can do that for `Environment.CurrentDirectory`  during your project by `FolderBrowserDialog` and like that.
In this situation, I think it's better to use `Application.StartupPath`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db");
string cs = $"Data Source={dbPath}";
using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
con.Open();
```

Or this:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "F4F_Core", "F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db");
string cs = $"Data Source={dbPath}";
using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
con.Open();
```

The path may be one of these two based if your project is in the solution folder or not

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Hesam's answer, I tried this:

```
string connStr = Path.Combine("Data source=", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db");
using var con = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
con.Open();
```

...and got this:

> Invalid ConnectionString format for part
> "C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db",
> no equal sign found

connStr is:

> C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db

(the "Data source=" bit is not there)

So I tried this:

```
string connStr = string.Format(@"Data source={0}\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
using var con = new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
con.Open();
```

...so connStr is now:

> Data
> source=C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db

And it works.

Oddly enough, if I use "Application.StartupPath" instead of "Environment.CurrentDirectory", I have to leave off the backwhack:

```
connStr = string.Format(@"Data source={0}F4FDataSQLite_SingleTable.db", Application.StartupPath);
```

Which is preferable, to use "Application.StartupPath" or "Environment.CurrentDirectory"? IOW, which one will most likely never cause a problem when the app is running on a user's machine?

Comment: please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575688/preference-between-application-startuppath-and-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirec)

Comment: By default, The result is the same for both. But one of the differences is that you can't set a value for `Application.StartupPath`, But you can do that for `Environment.CurrentDirectory` during your project by `FolderBrowserDialog` and like that. In this situation, I think it's better to use `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: @hesamakbari: Yes, I'm going with StartupPath; thanks!